# How do I create a new Public Folder Calendar using the Exchange Management Shell?

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders

Is there any way of creating a public folder calendar using the Exchange Management Shell?

Outlook is not installed on the Exchange Server nor do I want to install it.  Access is very limited to client computers so I would rather create it from the server itself.  Surely it can't be that difficult to do?

I have tried using the PFDAVAdmin tool but it fails to connect despite numerous attempts and I have given up on it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the *creation* is possible with a cmdlet - [new-publicfolder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996405(EXCHG.80).aspx).  As you can see, there's no EMS syntax for setting that folder's data type, though you could [Add-PublicFolderAdministrativePermission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997986(EXCHG.80).aspx), allowing the user to do what's needed at that point through Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only use Outlook to create public folders for different content types than messages.